# Checking Metadata between two tables using information schema

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can i use information_schema to compare column names,data type,data type length between two tables.

Comment: Just let me know if my solution solved your request.

Answer (score 1):

Before going to the answer, I want to let you know that stackoverflow is a place where you can post questions in which you are struck'd up. So When you are posting a question, please post till which part you have worked on and where you are struggling.

Inorder to achieve this, you need to have two dynamic sql queries created for getting the column names,data type,data type length from the source table and destination table that you need to compare. Then insert them into two temp tables and can run a select query to compare them.

```
@srvname1 VARCHAR(100)
    ,@srvname2 VARCHAR(100)
    ,@SourceDB SYSNAME
    ,@TargetDb SYSNAME
```

The srvname1 and srvname2 belongs to the server name that you have the tables located and the SourceDB and TargetDB belongs to the various database.

Below is the code.

```
INSERT INTO #TABLIST_SOURCE (DATABASENAME
, TABLENAME
, COLUMNNAME
, DATATYPE
, NULLABLE)
EXEC (
'SELECT ''' + @SourceDB + ''', T.TABLE_NAME TABLENAME, 
             C.COLUMN_NAME COLUMNNAME,
             TY.name + case when TY.name IN (''char'',''varchar'',''nvarchar'') THEN    
                ''(''+CASE WHEN C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH>0 THEN CAST(C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR) ELSE ''max''END+'')''
                ELSE    
                    ''''
                END
                DATATYPE,
                CASE WHEN C.is_nullable=''NO'' THEN 
                    ''NOT NULL'' 
                    ELSE
                    ''NULL''
                END NULLABLE
                    FROM ' + @srvname1 + '.' + @SourceDB + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T 
                        INNER JOIN  ' + @srvname1 + '.' + @SourceDB + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                            ON T.TABLE_NAME=C.TABLE_NAME
                            and T.TABLE_CATALOG=C.TABLE_CATALOG
                            and T.TABLE_SCHEMA=C.TABLE_SCHEMA
                         INNER JOIN ' + @srvname1 + '.' + @SourceDB + '.sys.types TY
                        ON C.DATA_TYPE =TY.name     
                        ORDER BY TABLENAME, COLUMNNAME,C.ORDINAL_POSITION'
);

INSERT INTO #TABLIST_TARGET (DATABASENAME
, TABLENAME
, COLUMNNAME
, DATATYPE
, NULLABLE)
EXEC (
'SELECT ''' + @TargetDB + ''', T.TABLE_NAME TABLENAME, 
             C.COLUMN_NAME COLUMNNAME,
             TY.name + case when TY.name IN (''char'',''varchar'',''nvarchar'') THEN    
                ''(''+CASE WHEN C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH>0 THEN CAST(C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR) ELSE ''max''END+'')''
                ELSE    
                    ''''
                END
                DATATYPE,
                CASE WHEN C.is_nullable=''NO'' THEN 
                    ''NOT NULL'' 
                    ELSE
                    ''NULL''
                END NULLABLE
                    FROM ' + @srvname2 + '.' + @TargetDB + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T 
                        INNER JOIN  ' + @srvname2 + '.' + @TargetDB + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                            ON T.TABLE_NAME=C.TABLE_NAME
                            and T.TABLE_CATALOG=C.TABLE_CATALOG
                            and T.TABLE_SCHEMA=C.TABLE_SCHEMA
                         INNER JOIN ' + @srvname2 + '.' + @TargetDB + '.sys.types TY
                        ON C.DATA_TYPE =TY.name     
                        ORDER BY TABLENAME, COLUMNNAME,C.ORDINAL_POSITION'
);
```

The above creates to temp tables one called TABLIST_SOURCE and another TABLIST_TARGET and inserts the column names,data type,data type length into them.

then run the below code which will compare the two tables and gives you the difference.

```
INSERT INTO #TAB_MATCH_RESULTS (SOURCE_SERVER
, TARGET_SERVER
, SOURCE_DATABASE
, TARGET_DATABASE
, SOURCE_TABLE
, TARGET_TABLE
, SOURCE_COLUMN
, TARGET_COLUMN
, SOURCE_DATATYPE
, TARGET_DATATYPE
, SOURCE_NULLABLE
, TARGET_NULLABLE
, REASON)
    (
    SELECT
        @srvname1 AS SOURCE_SERVER,
        @srvname2 AS TARGET_SERVER,
        @SourceDB AS SOURCE_DATABASE,
        @TargetDb AS TARGET_DATABASE,
        TS.TABLENAME,
        TT.TABLENAME,
        TS.COLUMNNAME,
        TT.COLUMNNAME,
        TS.DATATYPE,
        TT.DATATYPE,
        TS.NULLABLE,
        TT.NULLABLE,
        CASE
            WHEN (TS.TABLENAME <> TT.TABLENAME) THEN 'FAIL'
            WHEN (TS.COLUMNNAME <> TT.COLUMNNAME) THEN 'FAIL'
            WHEN (TS.DATATYPE <> TT.DATATYPE) THEN 'FAIL'
            WHEN (TS.NULLABLE <> TT.NULLABLE) THEN 'FAIL'
            ELSE 'PASS'
        END AS REASON
    FROM #TABLIST_SOURCE TS
    FULL JOIN #TABLIST_TARGET TT
        ON TS.TABLENAME = TT.TABLENAME
    WHERE TS.COLUMNNAME = TT.COLUMNNAME
    )
```

In the above i'm creating another temp table to store the comparison details for the TABLIST_SOURCE and TABLIST_TARGET . have all these codes in a single script and finally you can run a query against the table TAB_MATCH_RESULTS  and get the mismatch details. Hope this will help you.